# Align Div Text Bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

For someone reason I can't get this `div`'s text to vertically align to the bottom I've tried just about everything except for solutions involving extensive code.

```
.products {
width: 191.25px;
height: 191.25px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 15px;
background: black;
color: white;
float: left;
text-align: right;
}

<h2>Header Two</h2>
<div class="products">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div>
<div class="products">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div>
<div class="products">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div>
<div class="products">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div>
```

If someone could help me fix my code so to vertically align the `div`'s text to the bottom.

EDIT: 
I have tried the following:

Adding to `.product`

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the content in an absolutely positioned `span` tag.  Then set the `div` to position `relative`.  You can then use the `bottom` property of the `span` to adjust its height within the `div`.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<div class="products"><span>Content for  class "products" Goes Here</span></div>
<div class="products"><span>Content for  class "products" Goes Here</span></div>
<div class="products"><span>Content for  class "products" Goes Here</span></div>
<div class="products"><span>Content for  class "products" Goes Here</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.products {
width: 191.25px;
height: 191.25px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 15px;
background: black;
color: white;
float: left;
text-align: right;
position:relative; /** Added **/
}

/** New Style **/
.products span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px;    
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/wD4yJ/

Answer (score 0):

what about giving the text another div?

I have modified your layout a little bit

```
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<div class="products"><div class="inner">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div></div>
<div class="products"><div class="inner">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div></div>
<div class="products"><div class="inner">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div></div>
<div class="products"><div class="inner">Content for  class "products" Goes Here</div></div>
```

And the have added these roles in additional to yours:

```
.products {
display: table;
}
.inner{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to align the text to the bottom you will need a separate class for the text itself. I would suggest to put the text on a paragraph tag and position in the div wherever you want.

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Wbf/)

```
<div class="products">
    <p class="bottom">Content for class "products" Goes Here</p>
</div>
```